# Two select buttons on one page

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have put one dropdown select button on my page for cars, it displays a price for the selected dropdown item and puts the value on the page, but I need to put another on the same page but for boats and the prices are different, but all I get is the price displaying in the cars column with the boats prices, but the car one works ok, I have tried and tried to change references but cannot get it to work, any help would be appreciated.

tried to post the script what I have on page but it would not let me

I have tried to change bits but it still shows the price in the car section.

thanks

Comment: put some code on what you have tried.

Comment: *tried to post the script what I have on page but it would not let me* http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51106/how-to-post-code-in-so

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div class="row flat">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <ul class="plan plan1">
     <li class="plan-name">Cars
     </li>
     <li class="plan-price">
     <select id="price" onchange="changeddl(this)" onchange="updatePriceDisplay()">
  <option>Choose duration</option>
  <option value="150">1 day</option>
  <option value="200">2 days</option>
  <option value="300">3 days</option>
  <option value="400">4 days</option>
  <option value="150">5 days</option>
  <option value="200">6 days</option>
  <option value="300">1 week</option>
  <option value="400">2 weeks</option>
  <option value="150">3 weeks</option>
  <option value="200">1 month</option>
  <option value="300">2 months</option>
  <option value="400">3 months</option>
  <option value="200">4 months</option>
  <option value="300">5 months</option>
  <option value="400">6 months</option>
  <option value="200">7 month</option>
  <option value="300">8 months</option>
  <option value="400">9 months</option>
  <option value="200">10 month</option>
  <option value="300">11 months</option>
  <option value="400">12 months</option>
</select></li>

  <li> <h3><div id="divprice"></div></h3></li>
  
     <li class="plan-action">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Signup</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <ul class="plan plan2">
     <li class="plan-name">Boats up to 4 metre's
     </li>
     <li class="plan-price">
   
 <select id="boats" onchange="changeddl(boats)" onchange="updatePriceDisplay()">
  </div><option>Choose duration</option>
  <option value="14.00">1 day</option>
  <option value="17.00">2 days</option>
  <option value="20.00">3 days</option>
  <option value="23.00">4 days</option>
  <option value="26.00">5 days</option>
  <option value="28.00">6 days</option>
  <option value="30.00">1 week</option>
  <option value="46.00">2 weeks</option>
  <option value="62.00">3 weeks</option>
  <option value="75.00">1 month</option>
  <option value="125.00">2 months</option>
  <option value="160.00">3 months</option>
  <option value="195.00">4 months</option>
  <option value="230.00">5 months</option>
  <option value="265.00">6 months</option>
  <option value="300.00">7 month</option>
  <option value="335.00">8 months</option>
  <option value="370.00">9 months</option>
  <option value="405.00">10 month</option>
  <option value="440.00">11 months</option>
  <option value="475.00">12 months</option>
 </select> </li>
   <li> <h3><div id="divprice"></div></h3>  </li>
   <!--   <li>
      <strong>08</strong> Responsive
     </li>
     <li>
      <strong>12</strong> HTML5/CSS
     </li>
     <li>
      <strong>15</strong> Flex
     </li>
     <li>
      <strong>10</strong> Mobile App
     </li>
     <li>
      <strong>Live</strong> Demo 
     </li>-->
     <li class="plan-action">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Signup</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

```html
 <script>
function changeddl($this){
$("#divprice").text($this.value>0?("Price: Euro's " + $this.value):"");
}; 
 </script>
```

Comment: any ideas anyone or should I be doing the my site a different way